# Closing Open Office through Java

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am reading a Open Office spreadsheet document by using the OpenOffice.org API.

The problem is, I am unable to stop the OpenOffice process. The document closes, but the process keeps running(as indicated as Task Manager). Hence jvm doesnt exist, even if i `write(System.exit(1))`. I have to manually end the process in Task Manager.

```
ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
if (loader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
    URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) loader;
    Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
    try {
        Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(cl, new Object[]{new File(ooBaseDirectory).toURL()});
    } catch (Exception e) {
    CatchHelper.catchException(e);
    }
}
```

I have seen all options given at

> http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Closing_Documents

and also used the `XDesktop.terminate()` option.

However, nothing seems to work.

- Java Version : JDK 1.6 Update 14
- OS: Windows XP(same seen on Windows
  7)
- Open Office: Version 3.2 (Software cannot be upgraded)